# In Drupal How to filter or hide/show the tabs/fields on content page

Tags: drupal

My Question is, can we hide/show the fields on the content page for a particular content type in drupal 9 ?

Eg : if i select "A" from drop-down, I want to hide some fields/tabs(might be mandatory or non-mandatory fields). If I select "B" again I want to show some different fields. If I select "None" All fields should be visible.

Here is the screenshot [hide/show tabs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foPZD.png)

According to screenshot : Select LP type(Gated Content), I want to show only tabs like "Banner | SEO | Location" other tabs should be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal have several different ways to implement this, but you should start by looking at:

structure -> content type -> landing page -> manage form display.

If the field (and tabs) are not there, there can be other ways to find it, but you will need to look into custom modules and theme hooks.
PS: theme debug can also help you with it.

https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/understanding-hooks

https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/debugging-twig-templates